# (Chart.js) web page doesn't display chart, no error in console

Tags: charts, chart.js2

I'm new on chart.js and try to build something simple.
I've not error in the console but chart doesn't display on my web page. I have no idea where it's from.

It would be really great if somebody could help.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="center"><canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas></div>

  <script>


    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var datas = {
        labels: ["2010", "2011", "2012", "2013"],
        datasets: [
            {
                type: "line",
                data : [150,200,250,150],
                color:"#878BB6",
            },
            {
                type: "line",
                data : [250,100,150,10],
                color : "#4ACAB4",
            }
        ]
    }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for me the problem was that i used the same canvas name on two places mistakenly which it why the chart was not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not constructing the chart correctly. Here is how it should be created ...

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: ["2010", "2011", "2012", "2013"],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'Dataset 1',
         data: [150, 200, 250, 150],
         color: "#878BB6",
      }, {
         label: 'Dataset 2',
         data: [250, 100, 150, 10],
         color: "#4ACAB4",
      }]
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div id="center">
   <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

To learn more about ChartJS, refer to the [official documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/).

Comment: you right, I didn't built it the good way. Thank you very much ℊααnd